# Firebase with python-firebase throws up "Connection reset by peer" (Celery + gevent involvement)

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, firebase, gevent

I am using [python-firebase](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/) to record click counts and other event data in my stack. Its working fine but every now and then it throws up this stack trace:

```
'ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'somebase.firebaseio.com\',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /campaigns/79/clicked.json
(Caused by <class \'socket.error\'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)",),)'
```

This generally happens during peak load times but I know that I have not exceeded the 50 Max Connections available in the developer plan:

[image: Firebase Usage Data]

Some more data:

The click count update happens in a task queue using Celery with gevent. Could it be caused by Gevent?

**Update:**

Another error:

```
Task core.campaign.tasks.process_entry_click with id 
932df1ff-62a4-4d24-b491-b9b4921a2372 raised exception:
"SSLError(SSLError(SSLError('The read operation timed out',),),)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might happen during server code pushes or downtime (which are logged at https://twitter.com/FirebaseStatus) - it's probably best to catch exceptions like those and retry when the servers are responsive again.